# Can't add field with inverse relation

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I added field

```
class account_invoice_line(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'account.invoice.line'

_columns = {
        'rel_stock_move_ids': fields.one2many('stock.move', 'invoice_line_id', string='Moves')
    }
```

but getting error

```
invf = comodel._fields[self.inverse_name]
KeyError: 'invoice_line_id'
```

why my inverse_name is not working? as there is field `invoice_line_id` in `stock.move`

and in stock.move I have

```
class stock_move(osv.osv):
    _inherit = "stock.move"

    _columns = {
        'invoice_line_id': fields.many2one(
            'account.invoice.line', 'Invoice Line', readonly=True
        ),
    }
```

Comment: Where is `invoice_line_id` defined on the `stock.move` model? I don't see it anywhere in core code. Do you have it defined in a custom module?

Comment: @travisw sorry , updated my question

Comment: Is there any reason you are using old API (`osv.osv` and `_columns`) instead of new API (`models.Model` without `_columns`) since you are on Odoo 9? It might alleviate some of the issues you are having. Otherwise, your code looks like it should work as long as your files are being imported. You might have to import your `stock.move` file prior to the `account.invoice.line` file for old API (I'm not really sure)

Comment: yeh i needed to add dependency

Comment: If you have solved your question, then you should post an answer and accept it in case someone runs into the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The thing that I did not mention is that these 2 classes were in different modules. so I just needed to add a dependency in **openerp** file.